# dplyr - mutate data based on variable value

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to do a simple transformation. (preferably in dplyr) I want to create a new variable (varD) that is equal to the largest value out of three in year 5, in the years before that he has to put the variable equal to the value of the variable that was the highest in year 5, and after year 5 he has use the nominal change of variable A.

```
x <- tibble(year = 1:10,
            varA = seq(1, 20, 2),
            varB = seq(1, 100, 10), 
            varC = c(-10, -20, -30, 104:110))
```

should become

```
y <- tibble(year = 1:10,
            varA = seq(1, 20, 2),
            varB = seq(1, 100, 10), 
            varC = 101:110,
            varD = c(-10, -20, -30, 104, 105, 107, 109, 111, 113, 115))
```

I have the feeling that this kind of operation is cumbersome when using dplyr but I might be wrong...

Edit: The reason that I prefer doing it in dplyr is that I actually have another group variable defining the groups and thus I use group_by before. But other solutions that allow for groupings would be fine for me.

Edit2: I am looking for a solution where I do not have to specify in any way which is the largest variable in year 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
x %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(max = max(varA:varC)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(max_col = colnames(.)[max.col(.,ties.method="first")],
         group = ifelse(year <= 5, 1, 0),
         diff = abs(varA - nth(varA, 5)),
         varD = ifelse(group == 1, eval(as.symbol(nth(max_col, 5))), nth(max, 5) + diff)) %>%
  select(-max, -diff, -group, -max_col)
```

Comment: Thanks allot for the answer, however, it does not exacly behave as I was looking for. When changing the input to x <- tibble(year = 1:10, varA = seq(1, 20, 2), varB = seq(1, 100, 10), varC = c(-10, -20, -30, 104:110)) , then it chooses varA for years 1:3 while it should still take var C given that that var is the largest in year 5.

Answer (score 2):

`which.max(.[5,])` will return the index of the maximum value of the 5th row of the data.frame you piped in. We then use this value to calculate both possible values for `varD` as variable `a` and `b`.

Calculating these variables is actually pretty simple. Once we know the index of the variable we're working with, we can use bracket notation to subset the original data frame (accessed with `.` ). Note that we need to use `unlist` here since subsetting will generate a 1-variable data.frame, while `mutate` expects a vector.

We can then use an `if_else` expression based on `row_number` to chose between these two variables when we create `varD`. Finally, we remove `a` and `b` since they're no longer needed.

```
x %>%
    mutate(a = unlist(.[,which.max(.[5,])]),
           b = unlist(.[5, which.max(.[5,])] - .[5, 'varA']) + varA,
           varD = if_else(row_number() <= 5, a, b)) %>%
    select(-c(a,b))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
    year  varA  varB  varC  varD
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1   -10   -10
 2     2     3    11   -20   -20
 3     3     5    21   -30   -30
 4     4     7    31   104   104
 5     5     9    41   105   105
 6     6    11    51   106   107
 7     7    13    61   107   109
 8     8    15    71   108   111
 9     9    17    81   109   113
10    10    19    91   110   115
```

Comment: While I like the nice way of working with which.max(.[5,]) is still prefer the other answer given that I need it to work after a group_by(). With which.max this did not seem to be possible.

Comment: So you're looking to find the largest variable _for each group_, and this variable may be different for different groups? If so, you're right that this answer wouldn't work since `.` refers to the original dataset, not the grouped subset